# how to use seprate jni code for edittext use in another jni c project in android

Tags: android-ndk, android-edittext

I have created project for edittext using JNI native.My code has compile and run both and display the edittext in emulator.I have another project which are also used jni native.
i want use the code of edittext other project for display edittext in emulator.Please give 
me any solution and example.I am new in Android.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple **.so** files in one Android app project. The Java code should load both libraries, but not necesserily together. Your Android.mk file will have two **include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)**

Actually, you can keep the **jni** folder from your **edittext** project separate, and write in bottom of the new Android.mk the line:

```
include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../edittext/jni/Android.mk
```

The relative path from one **Android.mk** to the other depends on how you keep the projects on your disk, like this:

```
MyProjects
  |
  --- edittext
  |       |
  |       ----- jni
  |              |
  |              --- Android.mk
  |
  --- new project
          |
          ----- jni
                 |
                 --- Android.mk
```

Comment: When we put whole project of edittext in  my other own project and where the code perform of edittext and in Android.mk give the path

Comment: then its give error No such file or directory.please help me and give me any example.thanks